# How to install libspatialindex on Google Colaboratory

Tags: r-tree, google-colaboratory, libspatialindex

To efficiently analyse spatial data with Python, I use the rtree spatial index library, relying on the libspatialindex C library.

I am able to successfully install rtree in the Google Colaboratory notebook using `!pip install rtree`.

As expected, this is not sufficient, as libspatialindex needs to be installed first, as confirmed by `import rtree` resulting in:

`OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file`

I am unsure whether and how to install external libraries in the Google Collaboratory. Following https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/wiki/1.-Getting-Started I managed to run `!curl -L http://download.osgeo.org/libspatialindex/spatialindex-src-1.8.5.tar.gz | tar xz` but I do not have permissions for configure:
`!spatialindex-src-1.8.5/configure`

`/bin/sh: 1: spatialindex-src-1.8.5/configure: Permission denied`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: Looks like the bug has been fixed. Building no longer requires the `!mount ...` command below. I've updated [the example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1N7i9zmOwVcUzd4eHWZux4p_WTBMZHi8C) accordingly.

The original response follows.

This looks like a Colab bug. The `/content` directory is mounted with `noexec`, which is what's causing the permissions error.

Until that's fixed, you can remount `/content` with the `exec` permissions you need using the command:

`!mount -o remount,exec /content`

Here's a complete notebook that installs `libspatialindex` and `rtree`.
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1N7i9zmOwVcUzd4eHWZux4p_WTBMZHi8C

Comment: thanks for a fantastic response, this helps a lot. ONe minor additional question - is there a way to persist this install between notebooks ( collab newbie here, so I am not sure). I acknowledge that this follow up question is OOT

Comment: The easiest way to configure it probably to add a cell at the top in a collapsed section that performs the install if needed, e.g., https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1BawUdNVyRKl87_jVYEXCL3BXC14SW2AX

Comment: Yes, that would do it, but takes a lot of time and seems unnecessary between repeated use of the notebook.

Comment: Hi, I am having problem to fix this error: SError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file, i followed the notebook recommended here to install that library, but it still keep showing. I have to say that this error didnt appear before, i mean, i run one notebook without problems, and then i try to run it again, and this error showed up, and now I haven't get rid of it. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: To run the notebook you need the specify the version for RTree !pip install "rtree>=0.8,<0.9"

Comment: I was able to simply run `!apt-get install -y libspatialindex-dev` on a Colab notebook.